# Why does dynamic array contain null instead of actual string

Tags: arrays, c, dynamic

First of all, I dont know if heap memory is used in a contiguous way, with that do... while loop, second, when I try to print a string stored in the array, Im getting NULL value instead of actual string

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#pragma warning(disable : 4996)

int main() {
    int counter = 0;
    char** tab;
    do {
        tab = (char**)malloc(3 * sizeof(char));
        tab[counter] = (char*)malloc(256 * sizeof(char));
        fgets(*(tab + counter), 256, stdin);
        ++counter;
    } while (counter < 3);
    printf("%s", tab[0]);
    
}
```

Comment: Unless you're running on a *very* weird hardware architecture: Undefined behavior for accessing beyond the bounds of an object.

Comment: Im using online GCC compiler

Comment: You have massive memory leaks. Not only from the strings themselves but also because you allocate memory for `tab` itself inside the loop, throwing away the last allocation (and the string you just read with it).

Comment: As for your problem, take a closer look at the statement `tab = (char**)malloc(3 * sizeof(char));`. Are you sure you want to allocate three *bytes* for the pointer?

Comment: ohh... okay that's the problem. Thank you sir :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the code, `tab` should be an array of size 3 of pointers to strings. However there are atleast 2 mistakes

1. you allocate a new copy of the array in every loop iteration
2. you only allocate space for 3 characters, not for 3 pointers.

```
    do {
        tab = (char**)malloc(3 * sizeof(char));
```

So, your code should look like that:

```
tab = malloc(3 * sizeof(char*));
do {
...
```

Casting to `char**` is not required in 'c'.

Next line is ok:

```
        tab[counter] = (char*)malloc(256 * sizeof(char));
```

This line is ok as well, assuming that you are comfortable with pointer arithmetic.

```
        fgets(*(tab + counter), 256, stdin);
```

However, it can be expressed differently, a bit more readable

```
        fgets(tab[counter], 256, stdin);
```

Here is the working code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#pragma warning(disable : 4996)

int main() {
    int counter = 0;
    char** tab = malloc(3 * sizeof(char*));
    do {
        tab[counter] = malloc(256 * sizeof(char));
        fgets(tab[counter], 256, stdin);
        ++counter;
    } while (counter < 3);
    printf("%s", tab[0]);
}
```

Comment: Well, man, that is very thorough explanation, I was missing the point that 2d array is just a array of pointers to array of certain type. All I can say is thank you! I'm really grateful